# Move Over Something

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

If I have this:

> I moved my hand over the chair.

Is it ambiguous?  Because I think it can mean either:

1) My hand moved to the space above the chair and stopped there or,

2) My hand moved completely through the space above the chair.

Comment: Correct. You would need more context than that single sentence to know what was meant.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, the sentence is ambiguous. Here are two alternatives that reduce the ambiguity:

1) *I held my hand over the chair.* This is very close to your first meaning, *My hand moved to the space above the chair and stopped there*. The easiest way to *hold* one's hand over a chair is to first *move* the hand into the space over the chair. The other possibility is to hold one's hand still and move the chair into the space below the hand, but it is unlikely.

2) *I passed my hand over the chair.* The word *pass* means "to go by". This sentence has your second meaning, *My hand moved completely through the space above the chair*.